# C# Regular Expression, function "LIKE" in SQL

Tags: c#, regex

I want to search a word in a sentences which

word matches WORD, woRd, wORD, wOrD, etc...

so, this is what I have wrote:

```
string pattern = "[wWoOrRdD]";
Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
string input = "aa WORD aa WorD";
r.Replace(input, "word");
```

but the codes produce this:

```
aa wordwordwordword aa wordwordwordword
```

what I actually want is

```
aa word aa word
```

how to correct the error?
thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Igonorecase` option..

So,it would be

```
Regex.Replace(input,@"\bword\b","word",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

`\b` is a boundary which would allow us to match a single word but not a word within another word like `aawordaa`

Answer (score 1):

`[wWoOrRdD]` just matches a single character, you want `[wWoOrRdD]+`, which matches one or more characters.

you can make your regex case insensitive by making it `(?ix) [word]+`

also if your goal is to make strings lowercase, you can use the `toLower()` method like this

`input = input.toLower()`

Comment: `[wWoOrRdD]+` would not work..`input.toLower()` would also not work

Comment: he wants to match a `word`..`[wWoOrRdD]+` would also match W,O,r..`input.toLower()` would also lower other characters like a,b,c,d

Comment: `+` is greedy, it matches the longest string it can, as in "Word".  Therefore it will match WORD.  and I suggested `toLower()` if the goal was to make strings in general lower case

Comment: `+` would also match `DROW`

Comment: I was aiming to explain more why the specific regex you had wasn't working.  Some1.Kill.The.DJ  has the better "best practices" answer

Answer (score 1):

This regex pattern matches every single char (w/W/o/O/r/R/d/D),
You better use case insensitive matching.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\bword\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string input = "aa Word, aa WoRD";
string output = regex.Replace(input, "word");
```

[Fore more informatino about regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I should have used "\bword\b".